# How to convert any social media link to redirect to their respective mobile applications?

Tags: android, ios, url, deep-linking, social-media

I am planning to create a web application where people can convert their social media links so that their links will only open in the application. A great example for what I am looking for is [url genius](https://app.urlgeni.us/).

Notice how it creates protocol links for the corresponding links.
[image]
URL Genius almost supports most of the popular applications. I want to achieve the same functionality but was unable to find right resources.

So in a nutshell, how can I convert an ordinary link into their corresponding deeplink? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On Android, the applications declare which domain links they want to catch and handle on the app itself. So basically facebook app declares in their Manifest file that they want to catch and handle links that match www.facebook.com or their shortened urls.

I am not sure that I understand your question correct but, individual major social media companies already have a feature whereby if a user clicks on a link/ manually enters a link on a mobile device, then the user can choose to open the link on the app (deep link). More: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Answer (score 0):

Two options here that I would consider:

- Let URL Genius’ API do the work for you and just make an app that spits out the result
- Do the work to find each corresponding deeplink

There’s a good chance there’s a database of deeplink URL prefixes, but URL Genius has a list of their supported sites on their [API page](https://app.urlgeni.us/api). There’s only around 20 types listed there, and I’m willing to bet some use the same link prefix. Based on that list’s length, I’d guess it was probably handwritten. You could put in the same research to find those prefixes yourself, or you could use their API to avoid that.

As far as converting to a deeplink, most deeplinks I’ve seen are just the original link with the new prefix replacing http(s). I would start with that, run some tests, and manually fix the ones you find don’t work. Again, assuming you want to meet URL Genius’ number of supported sites, this shouldn’t take that long because they only seem to support 20 or so sites.

Comment: Thankyou for replying. I am planning to do the work by myself. Do you have any suggestion on how may I do this more efficiently? By the way I am planning to use JavaScript in this project.

Comment: For iOS, try searching with the term "URL Schemes". That's what Apple calls the prefixes on their platforms. There's [this link for Apple's apps and their associated URL Schemes](https://medium.com/@contact.jmeyers/complete-list-of-ios-url-schemes-for-apple-apps-and-services-always-updated-800c64f450f). You might be able to find something for third party apps as well.